# jquery .on() not working as expected

Tags: jquery

here is a link to jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5U4fT/
If you have a solution, please edit it there and send a link. Thanks so much!

The HTML is

```
    <html>
        <body>

           <a class="bonk" href="#">hi</a><br />
           <a class="make-new" href="#">add bonk class to dom</a><br />

        </body>
     </html>
```

And the Javascript is

```
   $('body').on('click', '.bonk ', function() {
       return false;
     }).each(function() {
        $('.bonk').click(function() {
            alert("hi");
         });
    });

    $(".make-new").click(function() {
        $('body').append('<a class="bonk" href="#">hi</a><br />');
     });
```

Comment: You're using `.each()` on the `body` element...

Comment: what is your expectation  ?what is the problem.\

Comment: read the API docs to understand why you are delegating with `on()` vs using `clcik()`

Comment: I'm delegating with on() to take care of dynamically added elements. using click only registers element when dom is first loaded. Your comment is less than helpful.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/5U4fT/1/

Remove the `.each()` and the excess handler.

```
$('body').on('click', '.bonk', function(){
    alert('hi');
    return false;
});
$(".make-new").click(function(){
    $('body').append('<a class="bonk" href="#">hi</a><br />');
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however, I need my code to include the .each() because for some reason on page load, if I click on an element with class 'bonk' it doesn't trigger, I have to click it, and then click it again. Any suggestions?

Comment: depends on other handlers within the page and event propagation - I can't really say without seeing all of your code... You should also wrap your code in a `document.ready` to be safe.

Comment: It is in document.ready.  If you are curious the website in question is http://www.metalgains.com , just click view demo and then login with the default credentials.  Then try clicking on a 'pencil'. It makes you click twice. I remedied this in the past by using a .each with the .on() but for some reason, this instance was just not working. You can create a new element by clicking the "Add Asset" button and then filling out and submitting the form to see a new element.

Comment: @user1888959 - You _don't_ need the `.each()` because you're currently using it on a jQuery object `$("body")` so there's only one item to iterate over...

Comment: @nnnnnnn yeah I had it not on the body at first, I had it written like this $('.edit-asset').on('click', function(){   but that didn't work either, even though it's pretty much verbatim to other snippits of code that i have using .on().